# How does Laravel / What pattern does laravel use to find config variables?

Tags: php, laravel

How does Laravel load config variables by returning arrays? For example:

**custom.php**

```
return ['foo' => 'bar'];
```

How can a file just `return` something?

Comment: **[This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6402039/1626250)** might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a.php

```
<?php return 'Scripts can return things!';
```

b.php

```
<?php echo include 'a.php';
```

Execute b.php and see what happens.